# Java BinarySearchTree and recursion in variables

Tags: java, recursion

i have a problem in understanding the following:

```
public int sort(char[] arr, int index)
{
    if(!isEmpty())
    {
        index = leftChild.sort(arr,index);
        arr[index++] = getContent().getToken();
        index = rightChild.sort(arr,index);

    }
    return index;
}
```

Why is that working but not this:

```
public void sort(char[] arr, int index)
{
    if(!isEmpty())
    {
        leftChild.sort(arr,index);
        arr[index++] = getContent().getToken();
        rightChild.sort(arr,index);

    }
}
```

And i also dont understand this : index = leftChild.sort(arr,index); What does this do? Can you guys pls give me examples?
Thanks for your help,

Kiimarii

One more question, i have a method that prints the longest way from the root to a leaf of the binaryTree:

```
public int height()
{
if ( !isEmpty() )
{
    int leftHeight = leftChild.height();
    int rightHeight = rightChild.height();
    if ( leftHeight > rightHeight )
    {
        return leftHeight + 1;
    } else {
        return rightHeight + 1;
    }
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

}

But how can leftHeight > rightHeight be done, if no one has a value? they are both zero or something so how can he compare that? Thanks !

Comment: It's unclear what this code does - what does it mean to sort a BST, what is `arr`, and what is `getContent()`?

Comment: There is nothing we can say about this code. You removed the assignment `index`, you need to debug your code to understand why it is important or just leave it be.

Comment: This method goes through the binary tree in in-order and put the elements sorted in an array. arr ist just the parameter for the array that should be sorted. GetContent just returns the content for example ( Token = 'a' , quantity = 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method performs an in-order traversal of a binary search tree.

The first snippet first calls `leftChild.sort(arr,index)`, which assigns the left sub-tree to the input array. It returns the next index to be assigned.

Then you assign `getContent().getToken()` of the current node to the `arr[index]`

Then the call to `rightChild.sort(arr,index)` assigns the right sub-tree to the input array and the next `index` to be assigned is returned.

If you ignore the `index` returned by the recursive call (as you do in the second snippet), `arr[index++] = getContent().getToken();` will always assign a value to the `0` index of the array (assuming the initial call is `(sort(arr,0))`).

You must assign the returned index to the local `index` variable in order to assign `getContent().getToken()` to the correct `index` of the array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i still dont understand this: index = leftChild.sort(arr,index); what does this do? I mean which number is assigned to index after this call? There is not +1 or anything that adds something?!

Comment: `leftChild.sort(arr,index);` receives the current value of `index` and returns an incremented value (incremented by the number of elements that it assigned to the array). `index` is incremented in `arr[index++] = ...`

Comment: @Kiimarii `arr[index++] = ...` increments the index of the local `index` variable. Then the method returns the incremented value of the `index`, so the caller gets the incremented value.

Comment: But if i call leftChild.sort(arr,index) isnt the local variable index again set to zero?

Comment: @Kiimarii the initial call to `leftChild.sort(arr,index)` is `leftChild.sort(arr,0)`, but that method returns an incremented value, which you assign to the index variable.

Comment: But isnt index = leftChild.sort(arr,index); calls this method again and again til he is at the most left child? And then he increments or not? I just dont understand  recursions in variables :( . when is index = leftChild.sort(arr,index); reaching the part: arr[index++] = getContent().getToken();?

Comment: @Kiimarii Yes, `index = leftChild.sort(arr,index);` is called repeatedly until you reach the left most child. Then `arr[index++] = getContent().getToken();` assigns the left most child to the 0 index and increments `index` to 1. Then 1 is passed to `index = rightChild.sort(arr,index)`. Then the incremented value is returned to the caller.

Comment: But why isnt that  working? :    `public  int sort(char[] arr, int index)
    {
     if(!isEmpty())
     {
         leftChild.sort(arr, index);
         arr[index++] = getContent().getToken();
         rightChild.sort(arr, index);


     }
     return index;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

The key is that `index` is a local variable. Let's follow a really simple example:

```
    4
   / \
  2   6
 /
1

// First call
(4).sort(arr, 0);

// The left child of (4) is (2)
// (Note that each 'index' here
// is a local variable.)

  index = (2).sort(arr, 0);
    // We've just called sort again
    index = (1).sort(arr, 0)
      // and again
      index = (empty).sort(array, 0)

        // isEmpty() is true
        // so return index
        return 0

      <=
      index = 0

      // assign contents of (1) to
      // arr[0] and increment 0
      arr[index++] = getContent().getToken();

      // Process right child of (1)
      // (index returns unchanged)
      index = (empty).sort(arr, 1);

      return 1

    <=
    index = 1
    ...
```

We're now in the call to `(2).sort` so its contents get assigned to index 1 of the array. Can you see how the sequence will complete in order?